# Why does my DNS Management service have an entry for localhost?

Tags: dns

I purchased a domain and signed up for the register's DNS Management service.  In their default configuration, they included an entry for localhost:

```
localhost       14400    A    127.0.0.1
```

What is the point of this entry?  Is it safe to delete it?

**UPDATE** I should clarify that I am familiar with the common roles that "localhost" and 127.0.0.1 play in networking.  I'm mainly curious about what this entry does in a DNS record.

Answer (score 1):

The point is to absolutely ensure that `localhost` resolves to `127.0.0.1` if your domain is in your search path. If you don't think that's important, you can delete it.

Comment: Can you clarify "if your domain is in your search path"?  What do you mean by search path?

Comment: A "search path" is a list of domains that you search. Say your domain is "example.com" and I go to the machine "www". If "example.com" is in my search path first, then my resolver will first look for "www.example.com" and, if it finds one, connect to that IP address. A friend of mine used to own the domain "router.com" and a huge number of people connected to his machine because they had "com" in their search path and were used to typing "telnet router".

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this entry only affects DNS searches from the server that my DNS Management company uses to host their DNS service?

Comment: No, you don't understand correctly. It makes no difference where the search comes from.

Answer (score 0):

localhost is the local DNS name for the loopback IP address (Local DNS name meaning that it is created by the local machine itself, and not from a DNS server), so that if you ping localhost, it pings the loopback address, the same as pinging 127.0.0.1, the loopback IP address. There's really no sense in deleting it.